# Multiple Actions, Same View and Validation Errors

Tags: asp.net, view, asp.net-mvc-3, models

Let's assume ModelState errors occurred in an action called AddComment(). AddComment does not have it's own view,  so instead of returning View(), we must return View("Blog"). We can't use RedirectToAction("Blog") because we loose our ModelState errors. The problem is what if the Blog view is bound to a Blog model?!? Let's assume we have an Index() action whose job it is to retrieve the Blog's data and returns View("Blog",BlogModel). We would have to copy the contents of Index(), where the BlogModel is retrieved, to our AddComment() action. Else, returning View("Blog") from AddComment will give us a null exception when the Blog view is being parsed. Is this the only way to maintain ModelState errors between actions that use the same view? I just started learning MVC and I'm still learning the right way to layout my code so please enlighten me.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        BlogEntry RecentBlogEntry;

        //get the most recent blog entry
        RecentBlogEntry = m_BlogEntryDataService.GetRecentBlogEntry();

        return View(RecentBlogEntry);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddComment(BlogComment NewComment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            m_CommentDataService.AddComment(NewComment);

        //get the most recent blog entry - AGAIN
        return View("Index", m_BlogEntryDataService.GetRecentBlogEntry());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. You should get the most recent blog entry again if there was a validation error so that you can correctly redisplay the view.

Comment: But if I had a blog page with a lot more going on I would end up with a lot of actions duplicating the Index action code. If I had to make a change in Index(), I would be forced to change the code in all the other actions. Then again, the alternative is to return to the days of viewstate where my model would be persisted from request to request. I guess I'll just have to make sure to keep all my logic out of my controller!